# Работа с Color в WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, color

Мне нужно в цикле при каждой итерации получать новый цвет, причём с плавным переходом, что-то вроде спектра. Как  можно это реализовать? Создавать какую-либо структуру или уже есть готовые решения?

Comment: Метод `Color.FromArgb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получать цвета можно так

```
    public List<ColorRGB> GetColors()
    {
        List<ColorRGB> result = new List<ColorRGB>();
        for (double i = 0; i < 1; i += 0.01)
        {
            result.Add(HSL2RGB(i, 0.5, 0.5));
            //do something with the color
        }
        return result;
    }

    public struct ColorRGB
    {
        public byte R;
        public byte G;
        public byte B;
        public ColorRGB(Color value)
        {
            this.R = value.R;
            this.G = value.G;
            this.B = value.B;
        }
        public static implicit operator Color(ColorRGB rgb)
        {
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(rgb.R, rgb.G, rgb.B);
            return c;
        }
        public static explicit operator ColorRGB(Color c)
        {
            return new ColorRGB(c);
        }
    }


  // Given H,S,L in range of 0-1
  // Returns a Color (RGB struct) in range of 0-255
  public static ColorRGB HSL2RGB(double h, double sl, double l)
  {
        double v;
        double r,g,b;

        r = l;   // default to gray
        g = l;
        b = l; 
        v = (l <= 0.5) ? (l * (1.0 + sl)) : (l + sl - l * sl);
        if (v > 0) 
        {
              double m;
              double sv;
              int sextant;
              double fract, vsf, mid1, mid2;

              m = l + l - v;
              sv = (v - m ) / v;
              h *= 6.0;
              sextant = (int)h;
              fract = h - sextant;
              vsf = v * sv * fract;
              mid1 = m + vsf;
              mid2 = v - vsf;
              switch (sextant) 
              {
                    case 0: 
                          r = v; 
                          g = mid1; 
                          b = m; 
                          break;
                    case 1: 
                          r = mid2; 
                          g = v; 
                          b = m; 
                          break;
                    case 2: 
                          r = m; 
                          g = v; 
                          b = mid1; 
                          break;
                    case 3: 
                          r = m; 
                          g = mid2; 
                          b = v; 
                          break;
                    case 4: 
                          r = mid1; 
                          g = m; 
                          b = v; 
                          break;
                    case 5: 
                          r = v; 
                          g = m; 
                          b = mid2; 
                          break;
              }
        }
        ColorRGB rgb;
        rgb.R = Convert.ToByte(r * 255.0f);
        rgb.G = Convert.ToByte(g * 255.0f);
        rgb.B = Convert.ToByte(b * 255.0f);
        return rgb;
  }

  // Given a Color (RGB Struct) in range of 0-255
  // Return H,S,L in range of 0-1
  public static void      RGB2HSL (ColorRGB rgb, out double h, out double s, out double l)
  {
        double r = rgb.R/255.0;
        double g = rgb.G/255.0;
        double b = rgb.B/255.0;
        double v;
        double m;
        double vm;
        double r2, g2, b2;

        h = 0; // default to black
        s = 0;
        l = 0;
        v = Math.Max(r,g);
        v = Math.Max(v,b);
        m = Math.Min(r,g);
        m = Math.Min(m,b);
        l = (m + v) / 2.0;
        if (l <= 0.0) 
        {
              return;
        }
        vm = v - m;
        s = vm;
        if (s > 0.0) 
        {
              s /= (l <= 0.5) ? (v + m ) : (2.0 - v - m) ;
        } 
        else
        {
              return;
        }
        r2 = (v - r) / vm;
        g2 = (v - g) / vm;
        b2 = (v - b) / vm;
        if (r == v)
        {
              h = (g == m ? 5.0 + b2 : 1.0 - g2);
        }
        else if (g == v) 
        {
              h = (b == m ? 1.0 + r2 : 3.0 - b2);
        }
        else
        {
              h = (r == m ? 3.0 + g2 : 5.0 - r2);
        }
        h /= 6.0;
  }
```

Информация взята от [сюда](http://www.geekymonkey.com/Programming/CSharp/RGB2HSL_HSL2RGB.htm)